# Schema-DDL generation with Ant for JPA-Pojos fails

Tags: hibernate, ant, jboss

I try to generate a `schema.ddl` from the `entity-pojos` using `Hibernate 4.1`.
Hibernate-Libraries including `javaee-api-6.0.jar` are in `WEB-INF/lib`. (Project runs on `JBoss 7.1.1`).
I dont want to use `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` for automatic schema generation.
So I have the following ant-target:

```
<!-- language: xml -->

<target name="ddl-generation"
    description="Export schema to DDL file">

    <taskdef name="schemaexport" 
            classname="org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExportTask">
        <classpath>
            <fileset dir="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib">
                <include name="*.jar" />
            </fileset>
        </classpath>
    </taskdef>

    <schemaexport
        properties="${basedir}/src/META-INF/hibernate.properties" 
        quiet="no"
        text="no"
        drop="no"
        delimiter=";"
        output="${basedir}/schema-export.sql" />

</target>
```

But when I execute it, it fails with following error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.logging.BasicLogger
    at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.findClassInComponents(AntClassLoader.java:1361)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.findClass(AntClassLoader.java:1311)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.loadClass(AntClassLoader.java:1064)
```

I can copy `jboss-logging-3.1.0.GA.jar` to the classpath of the ant-target, but then it fails, because `javaee-api-6.0.jar` is only for compiling:

```
java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/transaction/SystemException
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
```

What can I do to solve this?
Copy all `Jboss-Jars`?!
How does anyone generate a `DDL` from `JPA-Pojos` with `Hibernate 4`?
It seems to work better with `Hibernate3`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may find this blog post useful http://doingenterprise.blogspot.com/2012/05/schema-generation-with-hibernate-4-jpa.html It describes the process of generating ddl script from JPA 2.0 entities. Though it uses Maven as an example it can be easily adopted to Ant as it just runs a class with a main method. You just need to get the right dependencies. This list should hopefully cover all of them:

- hibernate-entitymanager-4.1.3.Final.jar
- jboss-logging-3.1.0.GA.jar
- jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar
- dom4j-1.6.1.jar
- hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar
- javassist-3.15.0-GA.jar
- hibernate-core-4.1.3.Final.jar
- antlr-2.7.7.jar
- hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.1.Final.jar
- persistence-api-1.0.jar